# How to get default value of choice field for the folder inside of a Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a Document Library and created one folder inside this library. Then I have added one choice field namely "Fruits" in this library. The choices for this property are Apple, Mango, Banana. During the creation of this property, I have set "Apple" as Default value. Saved the changes.

Now, I go to Library Settings->Column default value settings, there I can change the default value for both "Library" and "Folder". I changed the default value for the folder to "Mango". Now when I uploaded a document inside the library, the value of this choice "Fruits" property for the document will be "Apple". If I upload a document inside the folder of that library, the value for this choice property for the document will be "Mango".

Now my requirement is to get the default value of the folder programatically (C#).
We have searched over the scheme of List using the SharePoint manager, but could not find this information. 
Any clue will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.metadatadefaults_members.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-configure-location-based-metadata-defaults-in-sharepoint-2010/